# Apple DocC "BUILD DOCUMENTATION FAILED"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, docc

I'm trying to run `xcodebuild docbuild` using the following command to generate an Apple DocC `.docarchive`:

```
xcodebuild docbuild -sdk iphoneos -project MyProject.xcodeproj -scheme MyProject -derivedDataPath ~/Desktop/MyProjectDocC
```

The problem is with the `NotificationServiceExtension` module, as it fails the process with this error:

> The following build commands failed:
> SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for\ NotificationServiceExtension (in target 'NotificationServiceExtension' from project 'MyProject')
> (1 failure)

Is there a way to exclude the `NotificationServiceExtension` module from building?

It's ok when it comes to Xcode and

> Product > Build Documentation

The problem appears in command-line.

I tried `--exclude='./NotificationServiceExtension'`, but that didn't work.

This command didn't work either:

```
xcodebuild docbuild -scheme MyProject -derivedDataPath ~/MyProjectBuild -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12'
```

Comment: Does your project build ?

Comment: yes it does. as i said in xcode using "Menu > Product > Build Documentation" generate document. the problem is in command-line @PtitXav

Comment: I have also same problem